# Is there a PHP equivalent of Rails migrations?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, migration

Is there a PHP equivalent of Rails migrations?

Looking for a good solution for configuring schema changes locally and then automatically bumping them to the server without losing data.

Comment: PHP isn't a web framework like Rails; it's a language like Ruby and thus doesn't include an ORM. So, you can't really ask for PHP features that match Rails features.

Comment: Actually @flexxy is correct. Comparing PHP to Rails is like comparing apples to oranges. The comparison should be PHP -> Ruby, Zend Framework -> Rails. For the record I use Doctrine migrations.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised at how rude your comment is. The fact is that PHP is not equivalent to Rails, it's equivalent to Ruby.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Ruckusing](https://github.com/ruckus/ruckusing-migrations) Migrations is a "Database Migrations" framework for PHP 5.2+.

The framework is modeled after ActiveRecord::Migrations from Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Hi Sagi! 
just to throw two other solutions into the pool: https://github.com/apinstein/mp (has upRollback() and downRollback())
https://github.com/davejkiger/mysql-php-migrations
Does someone know how they compare to ruckusing?

Additionally what I would think usefeul for any "SQL-diff" based migrations-scenario are some sort of "keyframes" in the form of full structure dumps once in a while along the way, just to make sure mistakes during up() and down() dont add up when migrating in larger steps. If you have spotted those in the wild I'd be thankfull to know ;)

Comment: thanks, looks good. I will try one of them and update.

Answer (score 21):

My project http://github.com/robmorgan/phinx is a small lightweight migration engine without any bloat or big framework dependency. It borrows the best parts from several tools including ActiveRecord::Migration.

Comment: It has great documentation too: http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 6):

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), an ORM and DBAL, has got migrations.

Comment: And it's going to be deprecated for being ``unmaintained``: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-602

Answer (score 3):

http://github.com/nickinuse/php-migrations is built on RoRs approach

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw my hat into the ring, [Ladder](http://drarok.com/ladder) is a simple, pure PHP migrations system.